# Automated file transfer between two macs using an ethernet cable?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, tcpclient

Quick background, I am an intern at a company assigned to a project that I have no experience with, and I need some help trying to figure out where to start.

The goal of the project is to transfer very large chunks of data from a database, to a PC and then to a Mac. I am trying to code the communication between the PC and the Mac (this has to be done in c++, I've heard Python is easier but I have to use c++). Some requirements are that the PC and Mac be directly connected via an ethernet cable, and neither computer will have access to internet. The data transfer needs to be automated, so whenever the PC detects that it has received a full dataset from the database, it transfers the data to the PC. I cannot use any third party software to do this.

So far, through the research I've done, I think I need to set up a TCP Server-Client network. I've been using the code here (http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/practical/) as a guideline for socket coding. I am first trying to test this by sending files between two macs (I don't have access to a PC atm). Any guidelines as to where I go from here would be helpful. I have looked into setting up static IP addresses and such, but I get stuck from there.

I don't expect anyone to code this for me, I am just new to socket coding and this sort of project, so just looking for a nudge in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of company won't let their employees use third party tools, or even use a scripting language that's more suited to the task? They're just wasting time and money by forcing you to do this in C++.

Comment: The requirements are outlined based on third-party vendor requirements, and the requirements outlined by our servers/security requirements. These requirements make sense for the project when the whole picture is outlined... just makes my task significantly more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start coding, keep in mind that to connect PC to Mac you may need a [crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable).

Then do some reading on the wired ad-hoc networks. The last post in [this discussion](http://www.mac-forums.com/internet-networking-and-wireless/217983-direct-connecting-os-and-windows-7-via-ethernet.html) may help.

Finally, configure and mount shared volumes (using the stock software, no 3rd parties involved), and don't use the low-level socket interface.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion link, that will come in handy when I get a PC. Right now I am trying to accomplish this data transfer via two Macs, but I appreciate the resource.

"Finally, configure and mount shared volumes (using the stock software, no 3rd parties involved), and don't use the low-level socket interface."
-> What do you mean by low-level socket interface? And by stock software, are you referring to the link I posted? Just trying to reassure that I am on the right track by working off of that code.

Comment: @VarnitGrewal Stock software is the computer management applications which come with PC and Mac (device manager, control panel, etc). The actual transfer is just a matter of copying files.

Comment: I need to make this an automated process. I am working with another developer, who has coded a test to see when the PC has received a full set of data from our database. Once it is confirmed that there is a full set of data (it's just a flat excel file), it is my job to write the code that will automatically transfer this file to the Mac from the PC. Can this automation be done through Stock software? I was fairly positive I needed to set up the TCP server-client network.